# No type or protocol named 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' in -Swift.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I know i am not the first one to ask, and i'll probably won't be the last, but I haven't seen anything that helped me, so I'll ask anyway. I am trying to use some swift and objective-C for my Unity app, and I managed to do that much. But, as I am trying to use get my location in the background, I am trying to use CLLocationManagerDelegate like so:

Example.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocation.CLLocationManagerDelegate
import UIKit

@objc class Example : NSObject { 
    @objc static func StartTracking(){

        var att: FindMeTask = FindMeTask();
        att.StartTracking()

    }
}

class FindMeTask: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var bgtask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid;

    var coord: Coor = Coor()

    private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        return manager
    }()

    public func StartTracking(){
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations 
    locations: [CLLocation]){

        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else{
            return
        }
        let lat : Double = (mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let lon : Double = (mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        coord.SetCoord(aLat: lat, aLon: lon)
        if(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active){
            print("In foreground")
        }else{
            print("In background, location is %@", coord)
        }
    }
}
```

Example.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "unityswift-Swift.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocationManagerDelegate.h>

extern "C" {
    void _startTracking(){
        [Example StartTracking];
    }
}
```

And finally, my UnitySwift-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityInterface.h"
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"
#import "CoreLocation/CLLocationManagerDelegate.h"
```

So, with that code, it gives me this error: No type or protocol named 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' in my name-Swift.h when it tries to declare the @interface of my FindMeTask (@interface FindMeTask : UIViewController ).
Also, maybe it will help, I cannot extend an interface created in my .mm file by CLLocationManagerDelegate (like this: @interface test : CLLocationManagerDelegate)

I have tried many thing, but none have worked as of right now. If someone knows anything and could help, that would be great! Thanks in advance!